# cuSparse library

Tags: cuda, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to get my cuSparse library working. Following nVidia QuickStartGuide, I downloaded the library, extracted contents to /usr/local/cuda/include/ and compiled a test program whick gave me:

```
The following libraries were found:
CUDA   v5.0
Thrust v1.5.3
Cusp   v0.3.0
```

Now I'm doing matrix-vector multiplication:

```
...
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusparse_v2.h>
...
status = cusparseCreate(&handle);
```

The nvcc compiler doesn't agree with the last string:

```
/tmp/tmpxft_00000d0b_00000000-14_nVidiaSample.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_00000d0b_00000000-3_nVidiaSample.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x9fe): undefined
reference  to `cusparseCreate'
```

What's wrong here? By the way I work on Ubuntu, CUDA compute capability 1.2.

Thanks!

Comment: You must link the cusparse libeary when you build the executable

Comment: Thanks! If someone else needs it, in order to link cuSparse you need to add -lcusparse while compiling